# use variable req.body in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

My Mongoose schema:

```js
var book_listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  first_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  last_name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  newList: [],
});
```

In Express I have the post function

```js
router.post('/fileExpress/:title&:author?',...

var list_name = req.body.list;
var title = req.params.title;
var author = req.params.author;
```

```
 addToList[list_name] = [{book_name: title, book_author:author, date_added: new Date()}];
```

I've added this array to newList through mongoose push command.

```
 book_list.findOneAndUpdate({"userId": req.userContext.userinfo.sub},{ $push:{newList: addToList}},
```

This sends data to MongoDB that looks like this:

```
newList:Array
     0:Object
      read:Array
        0:Object
         book_name:"A Game of Thrones"
         book_author:"George R. R. Martin"
         date_added:2022-04-14T21:23:59.815+00:00
```

Inside this post function I have the Mongoose command

`book_list.findOne({"userId":req.userContext.userinfo.sub,"newList.list_name.book_name":title`

The code section `newList.list_name.book_name` does not work with the variable `list_name`. It does work when I type in the name of the actual list. In this case 'list_name' is 'read'.

I am using this because there will be lists with many different names and one function needs to work for all of them.

Comment: in your schema, `newList` is an array, so trying to access the property `list_name` would not work. Also if you are trying to interpolate a value there you would need `"${newList[list_name].book_name}"`. But again I dont think this will yield the results you want

Comment: as @about14sheep mention, you should define correctly your `newList: [...]` array structure (means the objects structure inside the `...` of the array .. so i guess it would be correct to put a structure like `newList: [{list_name: { book_name: String }}]`, i'm not sure but i guess it's something like this.

Comment: @about14sheep please see edit to comment

Comment: @sohaiebazaiez please see edit to comment explaining the array inside newList.

Comment: @DanielSemel your edited post still showing that the property `newList:[..]` in your **Schema({..})** definition is totally **Empty** and this made no differences (means you did not define any structure of your objects paths in the array) . i mean instead of writing this way `new mongoose.Schema({ userId: { type: String, required: true },  ... , newList: [],});` 
you should write this way: `new mongoose.Schema({userId: {type: String, required: true}, ...,newList: [{list_name: { book_name: String }}]}); // <=== HERE IS THE CORRECT`